# Consuming ssl-secured web service in web application

Tags: web-services, ssl, websphere

I'm building a web application that will run on a WAS using Rational Application Developer. This app consumes web services using https. Using SOAPUI I have no trouble using them but when I run the app I get security errors.

Any hints on what to configure so my app can consume this web services - that by the way use a self-generated certificate.

What about these ws deployments ? Should the WS's certificate be imported to WAS or is it covered programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make SSL connections from the WebSphere application server to external servers the server must be setup to trust the external server's SSL cert.

Howto: Add an external cert to the WebSphere 6.1 or 7 TrustStore

**From External Site/Port**

Step 1:

- Open the admin console
- Navigate to SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultTrustStore > Signer Certificates > Retrieve from port

Step 2:

- Enter the external servers host name and port
- Enter the external server host name as the Alias

Step 3:

- Save the configuration changes

**From PEM File**

Step 1:

- Open the admin console.
- Navigate to SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultTrustStore > Add

Step 2:

- Enter Alias and the location of the *.pem file > OK

Step 3:

- Save the configuration changes

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to do it would be to import the web service's certificate into the CellDefaultTrustStore.